# Modifying child elements using javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello I have the below HTML code and on a Toggle checkbox I fire this javascript function which is supposed to check all the checkboxes.The script is not working properly .Here's the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/eBFwq/

HTML

```
<SPAN class="Checkbox">

<INPUT id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_Chk_1" CHECKED="check" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$Chk_1">

<LABEL for="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_Chk_1">Check 1</LABEL>

</SPAN>
```

Javascript

```
function toggle(source) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('Checkbox');
    alert(checkboxes.length);
    for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].childNodes[0].checked = source.checked;
    }
```

}

Comment: The reason you do not put a class on the checkboxes to start?

Comment: If you are going to set up a fiddle, make sure it runs. JavaScript error. `SyntaxError: missing } after function body
http://fiddle.jshell.net/eBFwq/show/
Line 27` and you have the script running onload.

Comment: Hey that HTML is being generated by the ASP.Net checkbox control

Comment: basically debugging is going to tell you why. `console.log(checkboxes[i].childNodes[0])` It is not the checkbox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. You need to use index 1 of childNodes, not 0. 
Otherwise, you need to remove the whitespace between the two tags.

http://jsfiddle.net/H9mc2/

```
window.toggle = function toggle(source) {

            checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('Checkbox');
            // alert(checkboxes.length);
            for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
                checkboxes[i].childNodes[1].checked = source.checked;
            }

}
```

Also, if you have many checkboxes: 
instead of selecting all, I would invert the selection, like

```
function invertCheckboxSelection(e) 
{
    e = e || event; /* get IE event ( not passed ) */
    e.stopPropagation ? e.stopPropagation() : e.cancelBubble = true;

    var strFormId = "form1";
    var strCheckBoxId = "cbInvertSelection";


    var ControlCheckbox = document.getElementById(strCheckBoxId);
    ControlCheckbox.disabled = true;

    var form = document.getElementById(strFormId);

    for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) 
    {

        if (form.elements[i].type == 'checkbox') 
        {
            if (form.elements[i].id != strCheckBoxId)
                form.elements[i].checked = !form.elements[i].checked;

        } // End if (form.elements[i].type == 'checkbox') 

    } // Next i

    ControlCheckbox.disabled = false;
} // End Function invertCheckboxSelection
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the fact the first childnode is not the checkbox. There is a textNode.

```
console.log(checkboxes[i].childNodes[0]);
```

which is

```
<TextNode textContent="\n\n">
```

Since you said it is generated code, you should use `getElementByTagName()` instead of relying on the specific order of childNodes.

```
checkboxes[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked = source.checked;
```

Comment: I get this javascript error for this line  checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('Checkbox'); ..Object does not support this property or method..any idea what this might be

Comment: Runs fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/eBFwq/3/ Older IE versions do not support `getElementsByClassName`. Is that your problem?

Comment: [Because IE8 does not support getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.getElementsByClassName#Browser_compatibility). You would need to use a polyfill https://gist.github.com/eikes/2299607

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jquery ? 
I know you have not opted for jquery as a tag in the question but do consider using this.
It will make retrieval of child nodes so much easier for you. I went the Jquery way and cooked up something like this :

```
$("input").click(function(){
    var checkboxes = $('.Checkbox').children();
    console.log(checkboxes.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = "checked";
    }

});
```

**See the working fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/bbweR/2/**

Comment: @user505210 : for my script to work, you need to refer jquery.js in your project. If it does not work, then it's because you do not have the js, otherwise the fiddle is working as expected .

Comment: When I select the select all it checks the below checkbox but when I deselect it nothing happens..it should deselect the other checkbox too..